# C# -Connect unc path with credentials

Tags: c#, path, unc

I have a UNC folder added in my machine using "Add Network Places" option in "My Network Places" (XP).
I need to select the specific unc folder through my C# "folderBrowser Dialogue."
However,as unc path is password protected. While selecting the same,how can I prompt for userCredentials. can anyone have thoughts on this...

Answer (score 1):

PInvoke to WNetAddConnection2 and pass the CONNECT_INTERACTIVE flag to allow the OS to pop a username/password prompt if necessary. You can get the PInvoke definition [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr/WNetAddConnection2.html).