# Using UNC path with credentials

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-4.0

I'm working on an app that uses an UNC path to access remote files in the same LAN. The problem is that when access is attempted it throws an exception related to Windows credentials.

Is there a way to add credentials to my UNC path?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# -Connect unc path with credentials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879052/c-sharp-connect-unc-path-with-credentials)

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful for you to use the [NetUseAdd function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmuse/nf-lmuse-netuseadd) from the **Network Management Windows API**. It allows you to access a directory through its UNC path.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Win32 APIs are the most common way to handle this. Check out this SO post
[Accessing a Shared File (UNC) From a Remote, Non-Trusted Domain With Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials)