# How to access and read file using StreamReader on remote server?

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have a file on a remote server and I want to read its content.
Here's some code for example of what I want to pull off:

```cs
StreamReader str = new StreamReader(@"\\192.168.0.1\C$\Test\test.txt");
str.ReadToEnd();
```

This code is throwing:

> System.IO.IOException: 'The user name or password is incorrect'.

How can I pass any credentials?

My end result should be that I'm trying to access this 192.168.0.1 with

`user: admin` and `password: 123456`

I've searched on `StreamReader` documentation and nothing comes up.

Comment: may be its firewall issue Please allow port or disable firewall

Comment: Seems to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214596/using-unc-path-with-credentials or  https://superuser.com/a/344933

Comment: @NaveenSoni I've disabled the firewall and still have the same problem

Comment: @DorShamay Okay!! so try localhost first. @"\\127.0.0.1\C$\Test\test.txt" Is it working or not??

Comment: @NaveenSoni I'm trying to access file from remote server not from localhost, but from localhost its working.

Comment: You must have a unc network path and iis users full access(read and write )  for perform this action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using the following code:

```cs
    public class ConnectToSharedFolder : IDisposable
    {
        readonly string _networkName;

        public ConnectToSharedFolder(string networkName, NetworkCredential credentials)
        {
            _networkName = networkName;

            var netResource = new NetResource
            {
                Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,
                ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk,
                DisplayType = ResourceDisplaytype.Share,
                RemoteName = networkName
            };

            var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.Domain)
                ? credentials.UserName
                : string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", credentials.Domain, credentials.UserName);

            var result = WNetAddConnection2(
                netResource,
                credentials.Password,
                userName,
                0);

            if (result != 0)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(result, "Error connecting to remote share");
            }
        }

        ~ConnectToSharedFolder()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            WNetCancelConnection2(_networkName, 0, true);
        }

        [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource,
            string password, string username, int flags);

        [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags,
            bool force);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class NetResource
        {
            public ResourceScope Scope;
            public ResourceType ResourceType;
            public ResourceDisplaytype DisplayType;
            public int Usage;
            public string LocalName;
            public string RemoteName;
            public string Comment;
            public string Provider;
        }

        public enum ResourceScope : int
        {
            Connected = 1,
            GlobalNetwork,
            Remembered,
            Recent,
            Context
        };

        public enum ResourceType : int
        {
            Any = 0,
            Disk = 1,
            Print = 2,
            Reserved = 8,
        }

        public enum ResourceDisplaytype : int
        {
            Generic = 0x0,
            Domain = 0x01,
            Server = 0x02,
            Share = 0x03,
            File = 0x04,
            Group = 0x05,
            Network = 0x06,
            Root = 0x07,
            Shareadmin = 0x08,
            Directory = 0x09,
            Tree = 0x0a,
            Ndscontainer = 0x0b
        }
    }
}
```

And to use this way:

```cs
            using (new ConnectToSharedFolder(networkPath, credentials))
            {
                StreamReader str = new StreamReader(@"\\192.168.0.1\C$\Test\test.txt");
                var x = str.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(x);
```

This code is just exactly made for my question!

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to impersonate before you access the file. A post that will guide you [How do you do Impersonation in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net). once you impersonate you can access the file.

Comment: I'll try this approach, Thanks.